# What's the name of a robot manipulator construction with multiple thin arms joined together?

Tags: robotic-arm, mechanism

I am seeing on some videos robots picking items and putting them somewhere in order.

Here are some examples:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg8YYuLLoM0.
- https://youtu.be/ggFdvUlp8YU?t=38

How are these types of manipulators called and where can I find schematic illustration explaining principles of its work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are *parallel manipulators*.

You may find chapters on parallel manipulators in robotics textbooks, for example, [A Mathematical Introduction to
Robotic Manipulation](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf), useful. There are also a number of articles related to kinematics analysis of those manipulators (such as [this article](http://www.cis.umac.mo/~yangmin/journalpdf/J07-4-Li-Xu-RCIM.pdf)).